# Enable thread groups that are disabled by default

Tags: python, jmeter, toggle, jmx

I have a jmx file, when I open it in Apache JMeter, I see variable names with their values and some thread groups in the contents that are disabled by default. They get enabled by pressing <kbd>ctrl + T</kbd> on the thread group name.

How to automate this script in python so that it automatically opens the file and enables the group?

Tried pressing the keys but I am new to this, I was not able to achieve results.

Maybe this could work but it didn't.

```
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
```

[image: jmeter screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the toogle button at the top to enable disable thread groups(Highlighted in below screenshot). Once, enable then just save it and next time it will remain enabled.

[image]
Hope this helps.